# Changing input date data-type to DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY with require

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

Hi guys I'm creating an application for a region where date format is only in DD/MM/YYYY while the default input type date format in MM/DD/YYYY

```
 Jquery CDN added
 Bootstrap CDN added
<form>
 <input type='date' id='date' name='date' required>
 <input type='submit'>
 </form>
```

I can do this by placing a placeholder of `'dd/mm/yyyy'` in input because value is in format of `yyyy-mm-dd` that don't bother me but that require is creating problem. When a user gives wrong input in `mm/dd/yyyy` format it gives an error that date is incorrect so placing a placeholder will not work in this required case.

how can i change it to `dd/mm/yyyy` so it can work with required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this  use jquery's Datepicker.IN Jquery's Datepicker You can set any date Format You want.

Add this code in script tags at the end of body

```
<script>$('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();</script>
```

Just Add These Cdn's in head section in your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for datepicker, its working but still showing me data in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: @Azeem112 set the date format according to your requirement ' dd-mm-yy' here

Comment: thanks. It's working with this code $("#Date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

Answer (score 3):

According to Mozilla's article on the `<input type="date">` element, the user's operating system locale will affect how the date is parsed. So if you got a hold of a computer with an operating system set to your target region, it should behave as expected.

On the other hand, browser support isn't that great for `<input type="date">`, so I wouldn't depend on it. Better to use a date library that supports localization to validate.

If you're just looking for valid dates (and don't care about mixing up Feb 1 and Jan 2, for example), you could use the `pattern` attribute, put a localized regex in there.

Or, another alternative, render the full date next to the field (January 5, 2017) as they type it.

Mozilla's article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date