# Date format issue in mozila firefox

Tags: html, date, firefox

When I open my form in mozila firefox then date display in mm/dd/yyyy format as shown in below pic.
where as I want it should display in dd/mm/yyyy format even in firefox mozilla. here is my code

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of Appointment:</label>
        <input type="date" name="dateq" id="dateq" class="form-control" Required>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you might have installed the US English version of Firefox or download and install it in en-GB. There may be a way to choose a different region in the settings (e.g. en-GB) but right now it seems you're using en-US. Might be worth also checking your OS regional settings in case your default date format is US dates

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new answer.  I tried a quick search for "*firefox datepicker mm/dd/yyyy dd/mm/yyyy*" and found these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428046/changing-input-date-data-type-to-dd-mm-yyyy-instead-of-mm-dd-yyyy-with-require.  They suggest the format comes from either the browser language setting, or the OS language.  Have you looked into those things, or those questions?

Comment: @apokryfos  I installed GB version of Firefox but still date is showing in same format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: There's multiple suggestions presented by my previous comment. You tried one, have you tried any of the other ones? It's possible the non GB version you installed set some settings that any newer installation won't override.